# MQTT Communication over IPv6 not working in Java

Tags: java, mqtt, ipv6

I am running a java application communicating through mqtt. I am able to communicate using IPv4 addresses, but facing issue while trying to communicate with IPv6 addresses.

I have configured my router to provide IPv6 address. I am able to get IPv6 address when I connect my laptop to the router. When I run the code for localhost, it is working fine.

Below is the broker I have used for running the code for localhost on IPv6 which is working fine.

```
String broker = "tcp://::1:1883";
```

But when I try to connect to the IP address of another device on same network, I am getting error.

```
String broker = "tcp://[fe80::54d0:e4dd:96f4:98ca%wlx9cd643864a24]:1883";
```

I have also tried without the interface name as given below. But getting the same error.

```
String broker = "tcp://[fe80::54d0:e4dd:96f4:98ca]:1883";
```

Error:

```
Connecting to broker: tcp://[fe80::54d0:e4dd:96f4:98ca%wlx9cd643864a24]:1883 reason 0 msg MqttException loc MqttException 
cause java.net.UnknownHostException: [fe80 excep MqttException (0) - java.net.UnknownHostException: [fe80 MqttException (0) - java.net.UnknownHostException: [fe80 
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38) 
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:664) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Also it's not clear, is the IP address for the laptop or another device on the network?

Comment: "java.net.UnknownHostException: [fe80 " betrays that a host lookup is being done with a crippled host identification.  What this looks like most probably is something in your library that doesn't recognise IPV6 addresses properly.

Comment: Assuming Paho MQTT library, it should all be handed off to Java's URL parsing and not anything in the library

Comment: When I try running the code with ::1 to specify localhost for IPv6, I am able to communicate successfully. This is the broker that I am specifying for localhost: String broker = "tcp://::1:1883";

Comment: @hardillb, the IP address is of another device on the same network and I am using Paho MQTT library.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Please EDIT the question to add detail. But what you've shown for localhost is different to the other option as it has no [] round the address.

Comment: @hardillb, I have edited the question and added the localhost broker details. For localhost, without [], the code is working fine. But in java it uses predefined : for port, so I am adding [] around the IP.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but there's an interesting explanation about ipv6 addresses including network ids at https://superuser.com/questions/99746/why-is-there-a-percent-sign-in-the-ipv6-address .  (Read the 15-vote answer.)  It explains how when using linklocal addresses to obtain connections, the network address must be the one of the ***remote*** adapter (obviously) but the network id must be the one of the ***local*** adapter through which you want the traffic to go.  Why and how the UnknownHostExceptions appear can only be answered by someone who knows the internals of what you call.

Comment: if you use mosquitto_sub or mosquitto_pub tools does it work with the ip address you have provided ?

Comment: The text of the error implies that it doesn't recognize the brackets as the syntax for containing an IPv6 literal. Because you had it working with a different IPv6 address without brackets, that would be the first thing I would try.

Comment: @MichaelHampton when I give the address without brackets, I get the error as below:

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tcp://fe80::54d0:e4dd:96f4:98ca%wlx9cd643864a24:1883
atorg.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.validateURI(MqttConnectOptions.java:512) atorg.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:291) at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:185) at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.<init>(MqttClient.java:226) at com.mqttPublisher.mqttPublish.run(mqttPublish.java:1826)
at com.mqttPublisher.mqttPublish.main(mqttPublish.java:1999)'

Comment: @SantoshBalaji I haven't tried with mosquitto_sub or mosquitto_pub as the requirement is to run the code in java.